# Parent Child Multi dimensional array into single dimension array

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 1
            [name] => A > B            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 2
            [name] => A > B > C
        )
)
```

What I want is from multidimensional array a single dimension array like

```
array(
       [1] => A 
       [2] => A > B 
       [3] => A > B > C
     )
```

Comment: Sry the question is  iscomplete What I want is from multidimensional array a single dimension array like array(
    [1] => A
    [2] => A > B
    [3] => A > B > C
)

Comment: You can edit after posting, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54505308/edit.

Comment: You can use a simple `foreach` loop to achieve what you want http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: you can do that with `array_coulmn` function like https://3v4l.org/LnGBh but it will only work if your name is in correct order as your parent id other wise you have to use recursion(loop)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `id` index inside your elements is *unique*, you can use the function `array_column` to extract the relationship between `id` and `name` as ana associative array.
`array_column` accepts as the third parameter the name of the column to use as index of the resulting array.

[array_column Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

To solve your specific problem, you can use it like this

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => '0',
        'name' => 'A',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'A > B',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => '2',
        'name' => 'A > B > C',
    ]
];
$names = array_column($data,'name','id');
print_r($names); 
//[1 => 'A', 2 => 'A > B', 3 => 'A > B > C']
```

Comment: what  if   tow or more array have same parent id?

Comment: I made 2 big assumptions: `id` is _unique_ and `name` contains all the informations he needs. `parent_id` never was in the resulting array, so i suppose he doesn't need a tree, just an array that link the id of the node with the full path from the root, if more arrays have same `parent_id`, in the results there will be 2 index pointing to a same value, but i don't think that's a problem.
@NullPoiиteя Do you think i have to add this detailt to the answer?

Comment: I dont think so as far as i dont even know what exactly op wants lol :D

Answer (score 0):

Using `RecursiveArrayIterator`

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($records)) as $k=>$v){
    if($k=='name'){$singleDimension[]=$v;}
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/DQdg3